# Saving and loading R6 class object in r

Tags: r, oop, r6

I am trying to save an R6 class to disk and load it. The R6 class object is from the SBCK package in R. So, dOTC$new() creates an instance of the R6 class and the dOTC$fit() fits the model. Now I want to save the fitted model and load it back at a later time. How do I do that?

When I save the object using saveRDS and load it back I get 'Object containing active binding' and not R6 class object.

Comment: You should be asking the package author how to do this (or maybe reading the docs).  It often doesn't make sense to save the R6 object (because of things like active bindings), but in such cases the author might include an alternative method.  SBCK isn't on CRAN, which is often a signal that it is unfinished work in progress, so the author might appreciate being told of a missing feature.

Comment: Thanks. I have contacted the author. Awaiting a reply.